# How to add a programmatically created entity to a Data Service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, dataservice

Currently, I am able to create entities in my Data Service that are mapped to existing tables and views in a given SQL Database. The issue is that I do not want those very complex views to reside in the database. Is there any way to embed them into the Data Service or populate those entities programmatically?

As of now, I believe I have to use partial classes and create the entities on initialization.

I have searched and have not been able to find a solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You can create any type of entity you want, you just have to create the controller for it. Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @lc. Sure. For simplicity, I want a consumable entity that shows me all customers from a customers View in my SQL database. I want to remove that view from my database but by doing so the entity will fail because it is no longer mapped. How can I work around this and have that entity still work without the View existing anymore.

Comment: I wonder if you're sharing a data context between EF and odata, and that's where the confusion is coming from. If you have a separate context for odata, you can have a `CustomerViewObject` class for example in an odata entity set that has nothing to do with EF and your database. Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: @Ic. Thank you! Your comment got me looking in the right direction and I was able to figure it out (: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using these resources:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj730307.aspx

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52b1bb00-5226-46d0-b2ee-92aac0e82c22/the-type-is-not-qualified-with-a-namespace-or-alias-only-primitivetypes-can-be-used-without?forum=adodotnetdataservices

They show how to map entities to custom queries (residing on the dataservice) thus allowing me to eliminate the views from my clients' databases.